# Auto-indentation problem using Scite

Tags: ruby, scite

I am learning Ruby and use the Scite editor, but I found there is something I can not configure.

1. When I type "`def sayXXX`" and then I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, and then I type "`end`", now the "end" keyword is indented, so it is not aligned to the "def", how to make it?
2. Any way to make scite provide some Ruby related API content assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I type "end" I press `<Enter>` which unindents "end" back a level and then `<Ctrl><Shift><L>` -- delete current line. Sort of annoying but I'm used to.

Don't know much about solution to your second problem.